# Data wrangling in Django

Tags: django

I am new to Django framework, but have managed to put together a website with views, models, templates and connecting it to my database (Postgresql) through Django REST framework.

I am retrieving data from the database, but some of this data needs to be transformed (e.g. if positive = 1, if null = 0, or multiply all numbers by 100, and so forth). My question is, where can I do this in Django?

Should this be done somehow in model.py, view.py or serializer.py?

Apologies for the perhaps basic question, but I am struggling to figure this out.

My model.py

```
from django.db import models


# Create your models here.
class Test(models.Model):
    index = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    hash_id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True, blank=True)
    locality = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    page = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    latitude = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    longitude = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    ...
```

serializer.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from rentlistings.models import Test


class coordinatesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Test
        fields = ('latitude', 'longitude')


class propertiesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Test
        fields = ('price', 'price', 'yields',
                  'num_floor', 'num_rooms', 'elevator', 'garage',
                  'balcony_size', 'garden_area', 'parking', 'terass',
                  'loggia', 'cellar', 'hash_id')


class TestSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    coordinates = coordinatesSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    properties = propertiesSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Test
        fields = ('coordinates', 'properties')
```

views.py

```
from rentlistings.models import Test
from rentlistings.serializers import TestSerializer
from rest_framework import generics
# Create your views here.


class test_list(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
        queryset = Test.objects.all()
        serializer_class = TestSerializer
```

Comment: all your business logic should lie in views.py.

Comment: @Sumeet not so. It could just as well go in the serialisers.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I agree.

Comment: @Svarto could you include a specific example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of options, one thing I like doing for some transforms is adding a SerializerMethodField() and include the original field as well.

For example, if I had a field for a 'balance' and wanted to also include the boolean 'owes_money'

```
class MySerializer(serialiers.ModelSerializer):
      owes_money = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

      def get_owes_money(self, instance):
          return instance.balance > 0
```